# Problem using std::unique_lock on Multiple Threads - what(): Resource deadlock avoided

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex

### Description

- I have a serial connection object, `_serial`, that facilitates sending / receiving RS232 commands.
- There is one function, `sendCommand`, that sends data via the serial object.
- There is one function, `serialProducer`, that reads data via the serial object.
- I have to class mutexes, `_readMtx` and `_writeMtx`. Since RS232 can asynchronously read / write, there is no need to share 1 mutex for reading and writing.
- I use scoped `unique_mutex`'s to acquire possession of `_serial` to write / read RS232 data
- There is a main thread, in which a `QApplication` runs and a `_pollFasHbThread` thread that asynchronously call `sendCommand`
- There is a `_pollSerialThread` thread that calls `serialProducer`
- The `QApplication` calls this `sendCommand` via Pushbutton signals / slots
- The `_pollFasHbThread` calls `sendCommand`, 1x/sec
- The `_pollSerialThread` runs as fast as possible, with a 250ms timeout

### Class functions run within separate threads:

##### 1. Function to poll the heartbeat of another machine

###### Runs in `_pollFasHbThread`

```
void DASEmulator::pollFasHb()
{
    while(_connectedToRs232) {
        sendCommand("fas_hb");
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

##### 2. One of several Pushbutton functions

###### Runs in main thread

```
void DASEmulator::on_yawRunBtn_clicked()
{
    sendCommand("y_run");
}
```

##### Function that reads serial data (and places on queue)

###### Runs in `_pollSerialThread`

```
void DASEmulator::serialProducer()
{
    cout << "Starting pollingHandleSerial" << endl;
    char data[BLOCK_SZ] {};
    unsigned const timeout  = 250;
    unsigned const sleep_us = 0;

    while (_connectedToRs232) {
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(_readMtx);
            _serial.readString(data, FINAL_CHAR, BLOCK_SZ, 1);
        }
        if (data[0])
            _serialQ.push_back(data);
    }
}
```

### `sendCommand` function

```
int DASEmulator::sendCommand(const QString &command)
{
    QString fullCommand = "**" + command + ';';
    qDebug() << "Sending" << fullCommand ;
    char e{};
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock{_writeMtx, std::try_to_lock};
        if (!lock.try_lock())
            cout << "Could not acquire lock" << endl;
        e = _serial.writeString(fullCommand.toLatin1());
    }
    if (e!=1)
        cerr << "writeString error: " << e << endl;
    else
        qDebug() << "Sent: " << fullCommand ;
    return (int)e;
}
```

When I run my program, it will send the heartbeat command once, and then throws:
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what():  Resource deadlock avoided`

Comment: in `sendCommand` you acquire a lock (by constructing it with `std::try_to_lock`) and then immediately try to lock it again. Double lock all the way. Use `std::defer_lock` instead.

Comment: @JohnFilleau - That was totally it! Thank you.

Comment: Question: according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag), is states that ``defer_lock`` "does not acquire ownership of the mutex". 
What does this mean? Does it wait until the mutex is released?

Comment: It means you create the unique_lock on the underlying mutex, but don't lock it. Because you want to try to lock it later.